# Tips for golfing in S.I.L.O.S

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in [S.I.L.O.S](http://rjhunjhunwala.github.io/S.I.L.O.S/)? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to S.I.L.O.S (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

S.I.L.O.S can be run [here](http://silos.tryitonline.net).

Answer (score 2):

## Abuse the preprocessor

All SILOS programs can optionally have a macro statement on the **second line**

Consider the following program... One of my favorite SILOS submissions by betseg.

```
a=97
def q print z bottle v beer L Line g wall x IntNoLine h the c around
qL 99 zs of v on h g, 99 zs of v.
lbls
q Take one down and pass it c, 
a+1
qx a
qL  zs of v on h g.
qx a
q  zs of v on h g, 
qx a
qL  zs of v.
a-2
if a s
qL Take one down and pass it c, 1 z of v on h g.
qL 1 z of v on h g, 1 z of v.
q Go to h store and buy some more, 99 zs of v on h g.
```

Look at that savings
[Try it out!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=YT05NwpkZWYgcSBwcmludCB6IGJvdHRsZSB2IGJlZXIgTCBMaW5lIGcgd2FsbCB4IEludE5vTGluZSBoIHRoZSBjIGFyb3VuZApxTCA5OSB6cyBvZiB2IG9uIGggZywgOTkgenMgb2Ygdi4KbGJscwpxIFRha2Ugb25lIGRvd24gYW5kIHBhc3MgaXQgYywgCmErMQpxeCBhCnFMICB6cyBvZiB2IG9uIGggZy4KcXggYQpxICB6cyBvZiB2IG9uIGggZywgCnF4IGEKcUwgIHpzIG9mIHYuCmEtMgppZiBhIHMKcUwgVGFrZSBvbmUgZG93biBhbmQgcGFzcyBpdCBjLCAxIHogb2YgdiBvbiBoIGcuCnFMIDEgeiBvZiB2IG9uIGggZywgMSB6IG9mIHYuCnEgR28gdG8gaCBzdG9yZSBhbmQgYnV5IHNvbWUgbW9yZSwgOTkgenMgb2YgdiBvbiBoIGcu&input=&args=)

Answer (score 1):

## <s>Never</s> sometimes divide by 0.

Consider a challege where we should output the input if it is not 0 and output -1 otherwise. We could do the following.

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 50 bytes

```
readIO
if i b
print -1
GOTO c
lblb
printInt i
lblc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058rM00hUyGJq6AoM69EQdeQy90/xF8hmSsnKQcq6AkUzwTxk////28MAA)

However, that is far from optimal. The "superior" solution would be this.

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 33 bytes

```
readIO
j=i
i/i
j=j+i-1
printInt j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058ryzaTK1M/E0hnaWfqGnIVFGXmlXjmlShk/f//3xQA)

SILOS will quietly ignore the division by 0, which results in a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

## Never declare variables

There is no need to declare a variable. All variables are automa<s>t</s>gically initialized to 0.

Hence, this-

```
a=0
a=97
printInt a
```

Is the same as this

```
a=97
printInt a
```